# "A low LDL level" vs "low LDL level"

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, medical

Which is  grammatically accurate :

"Mrs.Anna has a low LDL level"

Or

"Mrs.Anna has low LDL level"

I want to go with the first sentence.

Comment: The second is "telegraphic" -- omitting non-critical words.  The first is more idiomatic.

Comment: Which one is better suited for formal writing?

Comment: Dropping the article is not suitable in either informal or formal running prose, only in headlinese/telegraphese.

Comment: **Level** is a singular countable noun. Singular countable nouns require a determiner.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Much appreciated.